# Django 2 recoger parametro pasado en la url dentro de una ListView

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, url

Si tengo una url por la que se pasa un parametro de la siguiente forma

```
http://mysite/person/car?parametro=1
```

En una ListView obtengo ese parametro de la siguiente forma

```
Parametro = request.GET.get("id")
```

Pero si el parametro se pasa en la url

```
"person/<int:parametro>/car/"
```

Por ejemplo aparecería en el navegador

```
 http://mysite/person/1/car
```

¿Cómo recojo el parámetro dentro del ListView?

de momento he conseguido que funcione de la siguiente manera

```
class MiVista(ListView):
    Model = Mimodelo
    template_name ='mitemplate.html'

    #recoger la variable para filtrar según su valor
    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        #obtengo el parametro 
        parametro = self.kwargs.get('parametro',None)
        #filtro mi modelo según el parametro
        queryset = Mimodelo.objects.filter(id=parametro) 

    # agregamos al contexto el parametro para poder hacer en el
    # template {{parametro}}  
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
         #obtengo el contexto actual
        context=super(MiVistam, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         # recojo el parametro 
        parametro = self.kwargs.get('parametro', None) 
         #agrego parametro al diccionario de contexto
        context['parametro'] = parametro            
        return context
```

Esto funciona en una vista, pero. ¿Hay una forma mas sencilla de hacerlo?

Comment: Hola, lo que no me queda claro es la razón por la cual usas un `ListView` si al parecer solo quieres el detalle de un solo objeto. ¿No sería mejor usar un `DetailView`?

Comment: si quieres un solo objeto, mejor es el DetailView cambia parametro por pk asi "person/<int:pk>/car/" y la vista se encargara de hacer el filtro y devolver un unico objeto

Answer (score 0):

Si ya tienes la URL tal como la describes "person//car/"

La forma para capturar el parámetro seria:

```
def nombre_de_la_vista(request, parametro):
    return True
```

Recuerda que, si cambias el nombre en la url tienes que cambiarlo en la vista también.

Comment: eso lo entiendo pero que cuando se trata de una vista basada en un List View

    class MiVista(ListView):
        model = mimodelo

   supongo que tendré que redefinir algun metodo de la clase para capturar los parámetros. ¿Cual?

Comment: Tienes razón, el parámetro se encuentra en self.nombredelparametro

 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    parametro = self.parametro

intenta y me cuentas como te va